# Can i run elasticsearch in server without using terminal

Tags: php, elasticsearch, terminal

I want to run elasticsearch in server without using ssh. i mean without making server listening `http://localhost:9200`. can i use the normal port  `http://localhost:80` in the configuration. Because making server listening require ssh

#### Update

Do i need to config the port 9200 before i use it??

Comment: You can change the port in the elasticsearch.yml file

Comment: yaa but can i use the normal http port?

Comment: I think you can ,but from now on port 80 will be in use by elasticsearch, anyway its simple to try

Comment: Elastic search should be started from cli if you don't have access to server bash you probably can't start it

Answer (score 0):

In the `elasticsearch.yml` you need to change `http.port`, and set it to be 80, or whatever you want.

Some additional info here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html

Comment: if i used the 80 port. Is it going to effect my website any way?

Comment: which website? why you want to make it 80 instead of 9200 or, let's say 81?

Comment: because i don't have access to the ssh

Comment: what is ssh in your understanding?

Comment: Am not using a localhost . I am using a real server